# Showing additional Dropdownlists on selected option inside a pop up in JQM

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm having a popup that currently shows one dropdownlist with options 1 to 4 and upon selecting an option I'd like using an ajax call to display that many additional dropdownlists (they are all displayed inside a popup window) . 
Is such a thing possible? 
So far I've created 4 divs for each of the selects and I hid them, is it possible to unhide them using a loop in JQM, after extracting the selected option?

```
<!--IceCream popup -->
    <div data-role="popup" id="puIceCream">
        <div ><center>Select Number of Flavors:</center>
            <select id="ddlNumFlavorsIC">
                <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
                    <!--Number of flavors is added here-->
            </select>
       </div>
        <div id="1FlavorIC" hidden>
            <center>Select 1st Flavor:</center>
            <select id="ddlFlavorsIC1">
                <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
                <!--Flavors are added here-->
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="2FlavorIC" hidden>
            <center>Select 2nd Flavor:</center>
            <select id="ddlFlavorsIC2" >
                <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
                <!--Flavors are added here-->
            </select>
        </div>...
```

JS Code:

```
$("#puIceCream").on("popupafteropen", function (event) {
    var NumofFlavorsSelected, Flag=0;

    if ($("#ddlNumFlavorsIC option").length < 2) {
        WebServiceURL = "IceWS.asmx";
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: WebServiceURL + "/GetNumofFlavors",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "post",
            data: "{ }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            error: function (err) {
                alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var size = data["d"].length;
                for (var i = 0 ; i < size; i++) {
                    $("#ddlNumFlavorsIC").append("<option>" + ((String)(data["d"][i].value)) + "</option>");
                }
                Flag = 1;
            }
        });    
    }
    if (Flag) {
        NumofFlavorsSelected = $("#ddlNumFlavorsIC option:selected").text();
        for (var i = 1 ; i <= NumofFlavorsSelected ; i++) {
            $("#"+i+"FlavorIC").show();
        }
    }
```

This doesn't seem to work though. Is it because the ajax call is asynchronous?
Any solution to this problem? perhaps a different approach?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the change event of the first dropdown to catch when a change is made:

```
$("#ddlNumFlavorsIC ").on("change", function(e){        
   NumofFlavorsSelected = parseInt($("#ddlNumFlavorsIC option:selected").text());
   for (var i = 1 ; i <= NumofFlavorsSelected ; i++) {
        $("#"+i+"FlavorIC").show();
   }
});
```

## **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/jARbmv?editors=1111)**

Your code with `flag` fails becuase it runs before the AJAX call returns